# Azure Databricks table not refreshing

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, databricks

I have Azure cluster setup that creates a table from a text file in an Azure Data Lake.  I then have another table that is a SQL statement based off of the first table mentioned above.  I update the text file in the Data-Lake and run a Refresh Table against the first table and all is good I see the changed information from the text file.  Then I run refresh table against the second table and when I query this table it doesn't reflect the changes from the text file.  Below is the specifics for each of the cells in the notebook that I have.

Here is the cell that creates the table pointing to the text file

```
%sql
Create Table If Not Exists Raw.ReferenceTables
Using TEXT
Location "/mnt/adls/Raw/SAP/sd13.txt"
```

Here is the cell that creates the table pointing to the Raw.ReferenceTables table above

```
%sql
Create Table If Not Exists Raw.CostCenter
as
Select ltrim(rtrim(substring(value, 9, 6))) CostCenterId, 
  ltrim(rtrim(substring(value, 15, 30))) CostCenterDescription,
  ltrim(rtrim(SubString(value, 45, 1))) CostCenterCategory,
  ltrim(rtrim(SubString(value, 51, 5))) ProfitCenterID,
  ltrim(rtrim(SubString(value, 56, 15))) StdHierarchy,
  ltrim(rtrim(substring(value, 71, 4))) CompanyId
From Raw.ReferenceTables
Where substring(value,2 ,3) = '048'
  AND substring(value, 1 ,1) = 'D'
  AND substring(value, 5 ,4) <> 'SC-1'
```

So now when I query the Raw.CostCenter the first time everything looked good.

```
%sql
Select * From Raw.CostCenter
```

I then updated the txt file in the DataLake and ran Refresh Tables against both the Raw.ReferenceTables and the Raw.CostCenter tables

```
%sql
Refresh Table Raw.ReferenceTables
%sql
Refresh Table Raw.CostCenter
```

When I query the Raw.ReferenceTables I can see the updated information, but when I query the Raw.CostCenter table I don't see any changes.  I tried just taking the query that defines the Raw.CostCenter and running that and it pulls back the results that I expect as well.

If I drop the Raw.CostCenter table and then Create it again then it will show the correct updated information.

I apologize in advance if I'm missing something basic because this is the first time that I have user Databricks for anything.  It seems very straight forward, but I just don't understand what I'm missing here.  Thanks.

I ran describe against the Raw.CostCenter table as described in one of the comments below and this is the results

```
CostCenterId            string  null
CostCenterDescription   string  null
CostCenterCategory      string  null
ProfitCenterID          string  null
StdHierarchy            string  null
CompanyId               string  null

# Detailed Table Information        
Database            raw 
Table               costcenter  
Owner               root    
Created Time        Wed Oct 31 20:35:50 UTC 2018    
Last Access         Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970    
Created By          Spark 2.3.0 
Type                MANAGED 
Provider            parquet 
Table Properties    [transient_lastDdlTime=1541018150]  
Location            dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/raw.db/costcenter 
Serde Library  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat     
 org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat 
Storage Properties  [serialization.format=1]
```

But I don't see from this what help this gives me to find out how to update the table.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to figure out where your data actually *is* in Databricks.

You *created* a new physical table by using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT to create a new table and copy the data from an existing table.  After running that statement there is no longer any relationship between Raw.ReferenceTables and Raw.CostCenter.

[Describe](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/describe-table.html) is your friend here.

And if you don't want a separate copy of the data you can create a [view](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-view.html).

Comment: OK.  I have put the output from the describe, but I don't see how that helps me.  Is there anyway that I can have a separate table and do something that will cause the table to update.  I guess I could create a view, but I would guess that this would be resource intensive as I added more and more logic into several layers of views.